# Load b43 module at boot

Tags: wireless, xubuntu, lenovo, 22.04, b43

How to do it? I need to type *modprobe b43* every time i turn on my old laptop, it's a bit annoying. I tried adding b43 to /etc/modules but that does not work. b43 isn't blacklisted on my blacklist.conf.

Comment: Let's see a full diagnostic report: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely `b43` is blacklisted in another file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf`.

Run `sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source` and it should be removed.

Comment: Thanks bro it worked!